# How to display client's installed software?

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement of getting the details of all the clients installed software. I have published successfully but when I try running in the client machine it is showing the server details only. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: You'll need something other than `asp.net` to do that...

Answer (score 1):

A web browser does not have access to the client operating system. That would be a terrible security problem.

You should consider using software that is made to do this sort of thing. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Most especially, wheels on a sailing ship aren't much good. That's what you're trying to do here.